# Differentiate the function: $v = x\sqrt{x} + \frac1{x^2\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus

Differentiate the function:

$$v = x\sqrt{x} + \frac1{x^2\sqrt{x}}$$

My attempt:

$$v = (x)({x^\frac12}) + {(x^{-2})(x^\frac{-1}2)}$$
$$v = ({x^\frac32}) + {(x^\frac{-5}2)}$$
$$v' = (\frac32{x^\frac12}) + {(\frac{-5}2x^\frac{-7}2)}$$
$$v' = \frac{3\sqrt{x}}2 - \frac{5}{2\sqrt[2]{{x^7}}}$$

Have I done this correctly?, and if I did, is there any more simplification that is required?

Comment: It seems correct.

Comment: Instead of the seventh root of $x^2$, you should have gotten the square root of $x^7$ in the final term.

Comment: @Sc4r : it's much easier and you are much less likely to make a mistake if you write $v$ using fractional and/or negative exponents before you take any derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct, except that 
$$
x^{-\frac72} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{x^7}} = \frac{1}{x^3\sqrt{x}}.
$$

With all these square roots you probably want to make sure that $x$ is positive.